# Read class properties in mvc4 T4 template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, t4, scaffolding

I am working on a T4 Template that will generate View Models based on a entities on core.
For example I have News class in Core and I want this template to Generate view models like these

```
public class News
{
    public property int Id {get;set;}
    public property string Title {get;set;}
    public property string Content {get;set;}
}

public class NewsCreate
{
    public property int Id {get;set;}
    public property string Title {get;set;}
    public property string Content {get;set;}
}
public class NewsUpdate
{
    public property int Id {get;set;}
    public property string Title {get;set;}
    public property string Content {get;set;}
}
```

for now just these two. but I could not find a way to get the properties of News class.
how can I use reflection to get them and . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your "News" class resides inside the same project as you want your views to be created in you've got two possibilities:

1. Build your project and then reference the output-assembly in the T4 template using 
   `<#@ assembly name="$(TargetPath)" #>`. Then you can use standard reflection inside the template to reach your desired classes. But be careful, you're always reflecting your last build that might be outdated and/or contain errors!
2. Have a look at tangible's T4 editor. It's free and provides syntax highlighting + IntelliSense for T4 templates. It has also got a free template gallery containing a template named "tangible VisualStudio Automation Helper".
   Include this one into your template and use the Visual Studio Code Model to iterate over all classes that are inside your current solution:

   ```
   <# var project = VisualStudioHelper.CurrentProject;

   // get all class items from the code model
   var allClasses = VisualStudioHelper.GetAllCodeElementsOfType(project.CodeModel.CodeElements, EnvDTE.vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass, false);

   // iterate all classes
   foreach(EnvDTE.CodeClass codeClass in allClasses)
   {
       // iterate all properties
       var allProperties = VisualStudioHelper.GetAllCodeElementsOfType(codeClass.Members, EnvDTE.vsCMElement.vsCMElementProperty, true);
       foreach(EnvDTE.CodeProperty property in allProperties)
       {
           // check if it is decorated with an "Input"-Attribute
           if (property.Attributes.OfType<EnvDTE.CodeAttribute>().Any(a => a.FullName == "Input"))
           {
               ...
           }
       }
   }
   #>
   ```

Hope that helps!

Comment: FYI; there's also roslyn which does text => syntax tree transformation which can be used for this. You could also define the model of the News in T4 and generate all variants from that avoiding external tools or reflection.